# Train rspamd filter

Tags: email, mail-server, training

I have rspamd installed and configured  as my spam filter of choice, along with dovecot and postfix. It's working well, but it occasionally misses the odd spam message here and there.

How can I train rspamd's filter through the terminal on some spam / ham messages I have on my disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally figured it out. The manual *really* isn't very clear at all on this essential functionality. To teach the filter about spam messages, type this:

```
rspamc learn_spam email_file1 email_file2 etc
```

To teach the filter about normal messages, type this:

```
rspamc learn_ham email_file1 email_file2 etc
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use **rspamc** to feed rspamd.

Comment: How do I do that?